# Detecting Mouse near a GeneralPath

Tags: java, java-2d

I've drawn a GeneralPath that represents a mean on a chart. Now what i need is detecting when the mouse is near it: i've used Line2d.segDist to detect if the mouse is near a Line2D object. Is there something similar for GeneralPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Stroke.createStrokedShape you can detect it for every [Path2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) object in a generic way (GeneralPath is a subclass of Path2D), see my answer for a similar question here: [Mouse pointer detection over a Path2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068726/mouse-pointer-detection-over-a-path2d/12069644#12069644)